# What's wrong with the [ ] pattern in php?

Tags: php, regex

Why does this pattern:

```
[A-z]+
```

Matches this successfully?

```
[][][][
```

Comment: Use `[A-Za-z]`. It matches according to the ASCII table

Comment: Because in ASCII the `[]` characters are between the lower and upper case letters.

Comment: You probably want `[A-Za-z]`, or use the `/i` option.

Comment: As others said, the brackets are between 'A' and 'z' in the ASCII table. Snippet: 

`for ($i = ord('A'); $i <= ord('z'); $i++) { echo chr($i); }` => 
`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_\`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`